# Question about terminology in number theory

Tags: number-theory, terminology

The following transformation appears often in number theory: $$F(x) = \sum_{n \le x} f \left( \frac{x}{n} \right)$$

What is the name of this transformation?

PS. I will accept as answer something that when I insert it in Google, I end up with articles about this sum.

PS2. As pointed out in the answers below, this is indeed called generalized Dirichlet convolution, see section 2.14 in "Introduction to Analytic Number Theory" By Apostol

Comment: What kind of articles involving this sum would you like ? I think a Google search with this information will give much better results than with some name for the transformation. Also, perhaps your requirement to accept an answer is unaccomplishable.

Comment: ok, this is not a very good criterion for accepting an answer. I will accept your answer below.

Comment: Thank you very much, I hope I could help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the standard terminology is the (generalized) Dirichlet convolution
$$
(\alpha\circ F)(x)=\sum_{n\le x} \alpha(n)F\left(\frac{x}{n}\right),
$$
where $\alpha$ is an arithmetic function, and $F$ is a real or complex valued function such that $F(x)=0$ on $0<x<1$. If $F(x)=0$ for all non-integral $x$, then this product is just the Dirichlet convolution $\alpha\ast F$. So your transformation is $x\mapsto (id \circ F)(x)$.

Comment: Are you sure? Typing "generalized Dirichlet convolution" in Google leads to only 5 results

Comment: The name for the translation itself may not be so common, but the product $\circ$ is often used (in the second Moebius inversion formula, or generalized inversion formula). By the way, I think "Moebius transform" is also not a standard terminology (google search mainly gives back "Moebius transformation", which is something different).

Comment: The name Moebius transform is used on MathWorld (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MoebiusTransform.html), but I agree that I do not know how standard it is.

Comment: Agreed, I will modify my question.